# Invalid identifier using dow function

Tags: oracle, function

I'm getting invalid identifier when trying to display the dow() for first_day and last_day.

Can someone please help me out.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dow(P_DAY DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN(TO_CHAR(P_DAY,'DAY'));
END;
/

 with starting_date (datum) as
      (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) from dual)
    select          add_months(datum, level - 1)  first_day,
           dow(first_day),
          last_day(add_months(datum, level - 1)) as last_day,
            dow(last_day)
    from starting_date
    connect by level <= 12;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a column alias in the same level of query it is defined (except in an order-by clause). You would need to either use another subquery to get the `first_day` and `last_day` values and then call `dow()` for those in an outer query, or just repeat the calculations:

```
with starting_date (datum) as (
  select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) from dual
)
select
  add_months(datum, level - 1) as first_day,
  dow(add_months(datum, level - 1)) as first_dow,
  last_day(add_months(datum, level - 1)) as last_day,
  dow(last_day(add_months(datum, level - 1))) as last_dow
from starting_date
connect by level <= 12;
```

| FIRST_DAY | FIRST_DOW | LAST_DAY | LAST_DOW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | SUNDAY | 2023-01-31 | TUESDAY |
| 2023-02-01 | WEDNESDAY | 2023-02-28 | TUESDAY |
| 2023-03-01 | WEDNESDAY | 2023-03-31 | FRIDAY |
| 2023-04-01 | SATURDAY | 2023-04-30 | SUNDAY |
| 2023-05-01 | MONDAY | 2023-05-31 | WEDNESDAY |
| 2023-06-01 | THURSDAY | 2023-06-30 | FRIDAY |
| 2023-07-01 | SATURDAY | 2023-07-31 | MONDAY |
| 2023-08-01 | TUESDAY | 2023-08-31 | THURSDAY |
| 2023-09-01 | FRIDAY | 2023-09-30 | SATURDAY |
| 2023-10-01 | SUNDAY | 2023-10-31 | TUESDAY |
| 2023-11-01 | WEDNESDAY | 2023-11-30 | THURSDAY |
| 2023-12-01 | FRIDAY | 2023-12-31 | SUNDAY |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HohnOLxe)

It's also not generally a good idea to use function names or other keywords as object names, including aliases; it's not complaining here, but I'd still consider calling the column something other than `last_day`.

You should also be aware the converting a date to a day name (among other formats) is affected by the session NLS settings, so someone else running this might see the names in a different language. And by default the day names are padded with spaces, which you might not be expecting.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise and response